# Comprehensive stats info on Baldur's Gate 2 shapeshifting effects?

Tags: baldurs-gate-2

I'm looking for comprehensive info on the various effects of shapeshifting.  There is a lot of disjointed info on the subject, but nowhere can I find a complete list.  I would like to compile that info here.

I did a little experimentation myself and recorded the Str, Dex, Con, THACO, AC, and # of attacks for each form, for both Jaheira and my PC (an Avenger).  That was helpful, but there is still some info missing.  For reference, here is what I collected on my PC.  Fields in parenthesis are presumably unique to each character and are thus for reference only.

```
            STR    DEX CON (AC)(HP)(THAC0) (Attacks) BaseDamage +x
Black Bear  18/100 12  18   6   90  13     3         ???        ???
Brown Bear  18/100 12  18   7   90  13     3         ???        ???
Wolf         18    17  17   3   90  15     1         ???        ???
Sword Spider 16    16  9   -3   72  16     5         ???        ???
Baby Wyvern  16    17  16   0   90  16     2         ???        ???
Salamander  18/75  19  15  -2   81  14     1         ???        ???
(Natural)    16    10  16   8   90  16     1         ???        ???
```

1) What is the weapon base damage used by each form?  What are the +x modifiers (e.g. +1, +2, used for checking weapon immunity)?

2) How does character level effect any of these stats or damage (if at all)?  How about things like weapon proficiency, dual classing, etc? (e.g. I noticed that Jaheira (F/D) had 1/2 more attack than my pure druid).

3) Which aspects of your current weapons and armor are utilized at all? (As far as I can tell, items such as Ring of Protection +1 do affect your AC when shapeshifted, but the base AC of your armor does not).

Browsing various forums, it seems that there may be some stat changes that don't work as intended (e.g. greater werewolf form weapon not counting as magical).  To avoid confusion, I would prefer that all answers only give stats which are actually in the game, not stats that were intended to be in the game.

Comment: Asking us to source something is off-topic. Just ask for what you're looking for.

Comment: Reworded to hopefully be clearer and more clearly on topic.

Comment: This is still several questions that should be asked separately.

Comment: Also, could you clarify if this is the original release of Baldur's Gate you're talking about, not enhanced edition?

Comment: This is the original release.  The goal was to get all the info in one place so future searchers can have a reference, and the questions are pretty interrelated, but i can split them if that's the consensus.

Comment: We prefer separate questions so searchers can get the information they want right away. It also works better in the Q&A format.

Comment: How would you recommend I separate it?  As mentioned, these are fairly interrelated.  Questions 1,2, and 3 will potentially impact each other ("how does character level and gear affect #1").  #4 could affect the stats table I started to assemble because it may mean there's another hidden stat that needs to be added to the table.  #5 is easy enough to separate out.

Comment: I think 1-3 just about work as one question. 4 can be separate but might be answered anyway. 5 is its own question about a specific ability.

Comment: Make the question "how does shapeshifting affect stats?" and do specifics about bears and fireballs as more questions.